# rename column titles unstacked data pandas

Tags: pandas, rename, axis, title

I have a data table derived via unstacking an existing dataframe:

```
 Day    0     1    2    3    4    5    6
Hrs                         
  0   223   231  135  122  099  211  217
  1   156   564  132  414  156  454  157
  2   950   178  121  840  143  648  192
  3   025   975  151  185  341  145  888
  4   111   264  469  330  671  201  345
 --    --    --   --   --   --   --   --
```

I want to simply change the column titles so I have the days of the week displayed instead of numbered. Something like this:

```
 Day  Mon   Tue  Wed  Thu  Fri  Sat  Sun
Hrs                         
  0   223   231  135  122  099  211  217
  1   156   564  132  414  156  454  157
  2   950   178  121  840  143  648  192
  3   025   975  151  185  341  145  888
  4   111   264  469  330  671  201  345
 --    --    --   --   --   --   --   --
```

I've tried `.rename(columns = {'original':'new', etc}, inplace = True)` and other similar functions, none of which have worked.

I also tried going to the original dataframe and creating a dt.day_name column from the parsed dates, but it come out with the days of the week mixed up.

I'm sure it's a simple fix, but I'm living off nothing but caffeine, so help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6])
df.columns = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]
```